# Plot dataframe w/ several columns in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe, which looks like this:

```
             0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9
0   112.394725  111.342734  114.268479  113.196259  110.550238  110.944990  121.012160  109.791914  112.128571  115.197597
1   111.654553  110.156635  110.745228  112.853603  110.617983  114.301398  115.837944  108.896795  110.302569  113.839373
2   111.884762  109.826058  110.832082  113.810005  107.848008  112.754423  113.943179  111.073987  109.355540  115.366171
3   114.119041  112.649403  111.409445  120.781897  104.208209  117.206310  112.997254  110.563350  107.082668  116.988650
4   113.107005  117.064107  111.610069  123.518242  105.500299  115.747012  113.315050  111.308931  103.827568  120.272026
5   114.507980  116.542394  113.718750  125.876949  108.628359  120.331237  115.103414  106.745611  104.203749  118.786569
6   115.506175  112.675418  115.965808  126.712737  108.398800  118.407694  114.838602  103.878543  102.284571  119.641274
7   113.963231  110.234802  116.360143  129.249053  108.410078  119.533443  116.521761  106.967450   98.845482  119.645353
8   116.497851  108.977773  116.014249  126.435175  104.626785  120.650270  120.646647  103.868224   95.522810  123.071141
9   120.067884  107.183546  113.836323  128.040669  106.267605  125.772287  119.284358  105.505966   96.077594  121.490413
10  116.489629  102.114210  114.250440  126.312382  108.858649  131.351122  124.624111  105.725993   98.024739  122.713557
```

What i'm plotting from this DF:

[image]

As you can see, the x and y labels are standard (along with the legend). What i wanted, was to customize it. I saw that plotly could be rewritten like this:

```
graph_simulationsa = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df.columns)
graph_simulationsa.update_layout(title=f'Simulação de Monte Carlo: {symbol}', xaxis_title='Dia', yaxis_title='Preço')
```

So, my main issue here is: **how can i pass X and Y in this new code**, considering that i need to pass several columns, *and not only one*? The same applies to the index. For a normal situation, **i could type: X=df['column1] and Y=df['Column2]**.

Comment: "As you can see, the x and y labels are not right" I can't see that at all. It looks like a plausible way to plot the sample data you showed. Please [edit] your question to describe what _specifically_ is wrong, and what your expected output would look like instead

Comment: Ok guys... I have just editted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [plotly express](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) like this:

```
fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = df.columns, template = 'plotly_dark')
```

#### Plot:

[image]

If you feel like sticking to [plotly.graph_objects](https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/), you can use:

```
fig = go.Figure().update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark')
for col in df.columns:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y = df[col], mode = 'lines'))
```

#### Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import datetime
from plotly.colors import n_colors


# data sample
nperiods = 200
np.random.seed(123)
cols = 'abcdefghijkl'
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 12, size=(nperiods, len(cols))),
                  columns=list(cols))
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),periods=nperiods).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0] =1000
df = df.cumsum()

# plotly express
fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = df.columns, template = 'plotly_dark')
fig.show()
```